# Why int() method does not work and string is not converted into interger?

Tags: python, integer

I have a following piece of code:

```
if (sum(L) % 3) == 0:
        biggest_list = []
        for i in range(len(L)):
            biggest_list.append(max(L))
            L.remove(max(L))            
        string_l = []
        for i in range(len(biggest_list)):
            string_l.append(str(biggest_list[i]))                   
        big_word = ''.join(string_l)                    
        big_number = int(big_word)
        v = type(big_number)
        print "big_number (should be number)"
        print t     
        return big_number
```

Why `big_number` variable is not converted into integer? And how to convert it into integer?
When I run this piece of code my Python 2.7.12 Shell tells me `<type 'str'>`
When it should `<type 'int'>` instead.

This is the whole function:

```
def answer(L):
    if (sum(L) % 3) == 0:
        biggest_list = []
        for i in range(len(L)):
            biggest_list.append(max(L))
            L.remove(max(L))            
        string_l = []
        for i in range(len(biggest_list)):
            string_l.append(str(biggest_list[i]))                   
        big_word = ''.join(string_l)                
        big_number = int(big_word)      
        return big_number
```

The function takes a list of integers as as input, checks whether it is divsible by 3 and returns the biggest number which can be comprised of these integers.

Comment: What do you mean by not converted? Do you get error/exception/unexpected behavior? Please mention all the information in the question

Comment: print `big_number` and add it in question.

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] to illustrate your problem? Your current code does not run because the code is not complete.

Comment: When I run this piece of code my Python 2.7.12 Shell tells me <type 'str'>

Comment: What is the function which is returning `big_number`?

Comment: def answer(L):
 if (sum(L) % 3) == 0:
  biggest_list = []
  for i in range(len(L)):
   biggest_list.append(max(L))
   L.remove(max(L))   
  string_l = []
  for i in range(len(biggest_list)):
   string_l.append(str(biggest_list[i]))     
  big_word = ''.join(string_l)    
  big_number = int(big_word)  
  return big_number

Comment: always add code (and other long information) in question, not in comment.

Comment: in current code you print some `t` but not `type(big_number)`. Where do you print `type(big_number)` ?

Comment: [this](https://repl.it/X3G/9068) returns an int. Do you have other code?

Comment: My guess is you accidentally printed "type(big_word)" and not "type(big_number)". After running this code (and only god knows what it's trying to accomplish)... it seems to run fine and big_number is of type 'int'

Comment: I tried `type(answer([1,1,1]))` it gives int.

Comment: BTW in one line `if (sum(L) % 3) == 0: return int(''.join(str(x) for x in sorted(L, reverse=True)))`

Answer (score 0):

[I think it's int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2m7w.png)

I don't get your question in fact